# <HTMLDivElement> has no method 'siblings'

Tags: jquery, exception, methods, traversal

Im trying to change a sibling of a div element and this is the statement i used

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    this.siblings('.innerInfo').html("success");
});
```

It keeps throwing the `<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'siblings'` exception, and i really cant figure out why. I've initiated jQuery and ive started the script on `document.ready`

thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you include the relevant snippet of HTML as well please

Comment: maybe use `$(this)` instead of `this`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

Comment: i knew it was something obvious as hell. thanks alot. havnt done jquery in a while im a little rusty ha

Answer (score 0):

You're should reference $(this) like:

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.innerInfo').html("success");
});
```